# Python Flask to password protect website with .htaccess similar to PHP

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask, .htpasswd

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/?ion=1&espv=2#newwindow=1&q=python%20%2B%20flask%20%2B%20password%20protect%20website%20%2B%20htaccess) leads me to these articles [01](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask-htpasswd) [02](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29725217/248616)

With `01` I don't know how to use it; recieving error

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.htpasswd
```

With `02`, it seems to be incomplete.

So how can we protect website with .htaccess password similarly the way we do with PHP website?

Comment: For your first method, you need to first install `flask-htpasswd`: `pip install flask-htpasswd`.

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer to get accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those solutions are perfectly correct. For the first, as has already been established, you need to install the `flask-htpasswd` extension first:

```
pip install flask-htpasswd
```

For the second, you'll need to show your implementation. But basically, the method requires you to create a custom decorator which asks for the authentication. You can extend it further by storing a logged in user's credentials inside the sessions.

Comment: Though I cannot get it work on AWS EB; it works on AWS EC2. Details as another question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/39031017/248616